# Theoretically speaking, is this possible?

Tags: macros, mouse, twitch

Okay, so I have come up with an idea that is based loosely on TwitchPlaysPokemon, I won't go into huge detail as it is a new idea, but I will cover the basics.

What I would be looking to do is have a program that can, in a game, move the mouse to a location and click on the screen, then based off of what happens in the next 5 minutes (which is the part I don't want to talk about), users in twitch chat will vote with 15 possible different outcomes in the form of !1111 through to !2222 (I think 15 is correct). This vote should trigger a mouse movement, and I will set the number of pixels I want the mouse to move in order to make this selection. Here is a screenshot of a very basic layout of what the in-game vote layout looks like: http://gyazo.com/0ab21fb235ff879e28d0f7a336ccf194

After the vote takes place I need to make 2 more clicks in a set location which will trigger the process to start again. If anyone could let me know how this would be possible, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, I can answer your question in two parts: a. I don't want to discuss this part. b. implement my suggestion in a'.

Comment: [No, it's impossible; computers are not that advanced yet.](http://www.bash.org/?5804) Seriously, though, I think that this question [needs to be less "theoretical"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before anyone will answer it. For example, [what have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick to the Windows platform you can do this with [Auto-it](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

It is a scripting language which allows you to move the mouse pointer, read pixel colours etc. I used it to cheat at Evony years ago, before everybody else also started cheating with [YAEB](http://evonybotdownloads.blogspot.nl/p/yaeb-yet-another-evony-bot-revision.html) and I lost (interest).